# Does $o_p(f_n)O_p(f_n) = o_p(f_n)$

Tags: probability, convergence, asymptotics

I know $o_p(1)O_p(1) = o_p(1)$ because assuming $X_n = o_p(1)$ and $Y_n = O_p(1)$

$$
\begin{align}P(|X_nY_N|< \epsilon)  &= P(|X_nY_n|<\epsilon\cap|Y_n| < M_\epsilon) + P(|X_nY_n|<\epsilon\cap|Y_n| \geq M_\epsilon)\\
&\leq P(|\frac{X_nY_n}{Y_n}|< \frac{\epsilon}{M_\epsilon}) +P(|Y_n| \geq M_\epsilon)
\end{align}
$$

But if $X_n = o_p(f_n)$ and $Y_n = O_p(f_n)$ wouldn’t $X_nY_n =o_p(f_n^2)$

Comment: Is $f_n$ a sequence of number ? or of random variables ? 
But in anyway, I think the it's $o_{P}(f_n^2)$.